# :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am facing one problem related to :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac message during application build. I tried so many solutions but all failed.

**Error log:**

Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCustomtabs2340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk4140Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComJpardogoMaterialtabstripLibrary110Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDeHdodenhofCircleimageview121Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
..........\test.java
Error:(178, 75) error: incomparable types: Object and int
Error:(180, 81) error: incomparable types: Object and int
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 14.073 secs
>   Information:3 errors
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

**build.gradle:**

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.1"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
}

**jdk location:**
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101

Comment: can you edit your question to include `test.java`? The error is: `Error:(178, 75) error: incomparable types: Object and int`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I complied the same code in another laptop. Now it is working.